# Why stdin returns error when displaying text?

Tags: lua

I am trying to run a simple program, but for some reason an error comes out.

I have version 5.3.5 with https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/. Installed on Windows version 10.0.16299.1087. The launch was made from `lua53.exe` command `main.lua`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmM4A.png)

```lua
print('Hello, World!')
```

Error Traceback:

```
stdin:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'main')
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Comment: What command exactly did you run to run the Lua file?

Comment: @CurtisFenner I entered the file name (`main.lua`) in `lua53.exe`

Comment: Please provide the *exact* command line.

Comment: It looks like you might be running Lua from an icon instead of a terminal. That won't work for running a `.lua` file. You need to find some way to open a proper terminal. (I'm not a Windows user, so I don't know how.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a .lua file from the command line, run

```
lua53 myfile.lua
```

Simply invoking

```
lua53
```

will launch a Lua *REPL* (ie, you can write statements that are evaluated not in the context of any file).

However, from the REPL you can use the `dofile` function to execute the contents of a file:

```
dofile("myfile.lua")
```

What you were trying to do, just writing `main.lua` inside the REPL, was attempting to use the filename as though it were a Lua script. Since `main` was not previously defined, you got that error.

Comment: You have not followed the directions properly. The screenshot shows you are entering code into the REPL. If you want to run a file from inside the REPL, follow the `dofile` instructions. If you want to run from the command prompt, quit the REPL and run from the command prompt.